# Docker Build SofteWare using Alphine Linux with Error 'install: unrecognized option: strip-program=strip'

Tags: docker, makefile, mosquitto

I'm building a mosquito docker image, when calling `make install` meet these error messages 'install: unrecognized option: strip-program=strip', please help, thanks.

```
install -d /usr/local/lib/
install -s --strip-program=strip libmosquitto.so.1 
/usr/local/lib/libmosquitto.so.1
install: unrecognized option: strip-program=strip
BusyBox v1.27.2 (2017-12-12 10:41:50 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: install [-cdDsp] [-o USER] [-g GRP] [-m MODE] [-t DIR] [SOURCE]... DEST

Copy files and set attributes

    -c  Just copy (default)
    -d  Create directories
    -D  Create leading target directories
    -s  Strip symbol table
    -p  Preserve date
    -o USER Set ownership
    -g GRP  Set group ownership
    -m MODE Set permissions
    -t DIR  Install to DIR
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/mosquitto-1.4.15/lib'
make: *** [Makefile:38: install] Error 2
```

Part of My Dockfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base openssl openssl-dev c-ares-dev util-linux-dev libwebsockets-dev libxslt && \
    cd /usr/local && \
    mkdir src && \
    cd src && \
    wget https://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-1.4.15.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf mosquitto-1.4.15.tar.gz && \
    cd mosquitto-1.4.15 && \
    make && make install
```

Call `make` the last several result lines:

```
cc -Wall -ggdb -O2  -c mosquitto_passwd.c -o mosquitto_passwd.o
cc mosquitto_passwd.o -o mosquitto_passwd  -lcrypto
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/mosquitto-1.4.15/src'
set -e; for d in man; do make -C ${d}; done
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/mosquitto-1.4.15/man'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/mosquitto-1.4.15/man'
```

Comment: Can you add more information, please? Repository and image name you're running, your commands before `make install`...

Comment: Hi @mulg0r, I have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're installing a `mosquitto` tar.gz with `/usr/bin/install` **version: BusyBox v1.27.2**, and your mosquitto's tar.gz downloaded with wget needs `/usr/bin/install` **version from GNU coreutils 8.25** for example, which includes your missing option `strip-program`.

> So, solution is simple: *install a mosquitto version for alpine*, not for generic Linux:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base openssl openssl-dev c-ares-dev util-linux-dev libwebsockets-dev libxslt && \
    apk add mosquitto
```

It'll install version 1.4.15.

> **EDIT:**  If you need to install a plugin and compile a generic linux tar.gz, you have to install **apk add coreutils**

Comment: Hi, @mulg0r, thanks for your help. I need to build it from source because I need to add a plugin for it. https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug. this plugin suggests I need a copy of mosquito and execute `make` from the source folder.So I can't simply `apk add mosquitto`  to install it

Comment: Hi @mulg0r, thank you very much. this is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the answer @mulg0r gave me. I found there was another way to solve this. I think this is also useful when someone meets a similar problem. From https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/mosquitto?h=master this link. the package from alpine Linux. Click the `Git repository` button, inside that page,  this package's build process instructions are there. And some code changes to suit alpine Linux.

For this question, find APKBUILD file from https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/mosquitto?h=master. this line also solved my question:

```
sed -i -e "s|(INSTALL) -s|(INSTALL)|g" \
    -e 's|--strip-program=${CROSS_COMPILE}${STRIP}||' \
    */Makefile */*/Makefile
```

Above is just comment out --strip-program when excute `make install`